# best way to skip a path/shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

I wonder if there is a conveniant way to skip a path/shape. For example, I can use `\draw (0, 0) -- [clip path={...}] (2, 3);` or `\draw (0, 0) -- [clip path name=<path name>] (2, 3);` or `\draw (0, 0) -- [clip node=<nodename>] (2, 3);` to skip the given path/node.

I know some code to do this, but they cost several lines:

### [Inverse clip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12033/201158)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  revclip/.style={
    insert path={
      (current page.north east) --
      (current page.south east) --
      (current page.south west) --
      (current page.north west) --
      (current page.north east)
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (1, 1) circle (1cm);
  \draw (0.6, 1) circle (0.5cm);
  \path [clip, overlay] (1, 1) circle (1cm) [revclip];
  \draw (0, 0) -- (2, 3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Background layer

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\pgfdeclarelayer{back}
\pgfsetlayers{back, main}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (1, 1) circle (1cm);
  \draw (0.6, 1) circle (0.5cm);
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{back}
    \draw (0, 0) -- (2, 3);
    \fill[white, behind path] (1, 1) circle (1cm);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[ (0, 0) -- (2, 3);
  \fill[white, draw=black] (1, 1) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}` do same thing. No `backgrounds` library needed.

Comment: @ferahfeza  I have changed my example to show the necessity of background layer.

Comment: Sorry I guess I could not fully understand your question. But this code also give same output: ` \draw (0, 0) -- (2, 3);
   \fill[white,draw=black] (1, 1) circle (1cm);     \draw (0.6, 1) circle (0.5cm);`

Comment: @ferahfeza yes, there are many ways, I am just assuming a situation that I am drawing a path with another path/shape on the way, and it cost a lot or is impossible to adjust the order of drawing to hide part of current path behind.